# show splash screen one time only

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a radio aac player I added a splash screen at the beginning, but I would like to show it just one time, because if user press back button my app stays on background with a music service playing, but when I go back to the app shows splash screen again. Here is my actual splashscreen code:

```
public class Inicio extends Activity {
       private Handler handler = new Handler()
        {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Inicio.this, ScreenTabs.class);
                Inicio.this.startActivity(i);
                Inicio.this.finish();
            }
        };

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            if(!prefs.getBoolean("first_time", false))
            {
                /* 
                // we will set this true when our ScreenTabs activity
                   ends or the service playing music is stopped.
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("first_time", true);
                editor.commit();

                */

                Intent i = new Intent(Inicio.this, ScreenTabs.class);
                this.startActivity(i);
                                     this.finish();
            }
            else
            {
                this.setContentView(R.layout.inicio);
                handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 2000);
            }
        }
}
```

Ondestroy of screentabs.java

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("first_time", true);
                    editor.commit();
    if(radioService!=null) {
        if(!radioService.isPlaying() && !radioService.isPreparingStarted()) {
            //radioService.stopSelf();
            radioService.stop();

            radioService.stopService(bindIntent);
            radioService.exitNotification();
        }
    }   
}
```

What can I change or add in order to show splash screen just first time app is initiated?

Comment: I set the Handler time to 0s to avoid the repetition of Splash Screen.

Comment: could u give me example in my code?

Comment: use shref pref,initialize it and then check the value everytime its start.if valye is greater then your value then alway go to next screen.

Comment: please give me an example for me too see it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Inicio extends Activity {
   private Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Inicio.this, ScreenTabs.class);
            Inicio.this.startActivity(i);
            Inicio.this.finish();
        }
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if(!prefs.getBoolean("first_time", false))
        {
            /* 
            // we will set this true when our ScreenTabs activity
               ends or the service playing music is stopped.
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("first_time", true);
            editor.commit();

            */

            Intent i = new Intent(Inicio.this, ScreenTabs.class);
            this.startActivity(i);
                                 this.finish();
        }
        else
        {
            this.setContentView(R.layout.inicio);
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 2000);
        }
```

Implement `onDestory` of the `ScreenTabs` activity and `onDestroy` method of the service and there

```
@Override
public void onDestory(){
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("first_time", true);
                editor.commit();
}
```

and similarly in `onDestory` of the service

```
@Override
public void onDestory(){
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("first_time", true);
                editor.commit();
}
```

What we do here that the preference value first_time which checks that Splash should be shown or not is set to `true` only when the ScreenTabs activity is finished or the music playing service is stopped.

Comment: please give me an example for me too see it :)

Comment: im getting error with editor.putBoolean("show_splash", false); and if(!prefs.getBoolean("first_time", false))

Comment: @alexistkd see me changed answer, understand it before you implement it.

Comment: @alexistkd wait I will make a small project for you.

Comment: @alexistkd download and test this project, I just developed for you https://github.com/rachitrm/inicio

Comment: i test it, but same, i click on start service then click home button or back button and then open app again and its shows the splash screen im using nexus 5 kitkat

Answer (score 1):

Add a shared preference with Boolean type and make it false and after first time splash page make it true so it will no go inside that method-

On Start Of Actitity-

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    Context context;
    boolean isScrennoFill = false;
```

And below OnCreate()-

```
context = this;
        /**
         * get user login preference
         */
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("savecredentails",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        isScrennoFill = sharedPref.getBoolean("isScrennoFill", false);

if (isScrennoFill == false) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                                SplashPage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                                Next.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

Comment: could u please give me example with my code? should u just change inicio.java or screentabs.java also?

Answer (score 1):

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` you can use `android:noHistory="true"` in the activity you want to disable going back to